# How to use UseSerilog in kestrel project

Tags: serilog

I have this boot code and I am trying to work out how to add Serilog to it.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server ;
using System.Net;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.AspNetCore;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
}
else {
    builder.Services.AddLettuceEncrypt();
    builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(k => {
        var appServices = k.ApplicationServices;
        k.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);
        k.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443,
            o => o.UseHttps(h => {
              h.UseLettuceEncrypt(appServices);
            }));

        k.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(h => {
            h.UseLettuceEncrypt(appServices);
        });
    });
}
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

I found Serilog.AspNetCore and have installed that package. The github home https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore says to add UseSerilog but I cannot work out how to wire that in.

I added

```
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.WebHost.UseSerilog(); <<<====
```

But this is deprecated and says

> warning CS0618: 'SerilogWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseSerilog(IWebHostBuilder, ILogger, bool, LoggerProviderCollection)' is obsolete: 'Prefer UseSerilog() on IHostBuilder'

But I dont have an IHostBuilder and dont see how to make one. Nor can I find a package with that extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `IHostBuilder` is on `builder.Host`.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder.host)

> An `IHostBuilder` for configuring host specific properties, but not building.

The call to configure `Serilog` becomes

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
```